# Links for switching locale on RefnineryCms frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, locale, refinerycms

I am using RefineryCms with Rails 3.2.10 and refinerycms 2.0.9.

I want to show on every page flags with link to switch language of the page.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used something like this :

```
= link_to image_tag(national_flag),refinery.url_for(:locale => nation_locale)
```

in case you've installed the `i18n` gem of RefineryCMS.

Comment: I suppose in your `application.html.haml` (or `.erb` ) , next to the login links . Refinery has a partial , named `_header.html.haml` , which is a proper place for i18n .

Comment: I have none of the above mentioned files in the source tree

Comment: I guess you are exploring Refinery from the beginning :) To override (expose) views , you should `rake refinery:override view=refinery/pages/*` and then you are ready to edit them all . Here is a [nice guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/overriding-views).